# Special characters parsing in Ktor

Tags: ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I am trying to parse some special characters through the api's with Ktor in a KMM project but it seems like Ktor doesn't support it ?.

For eg :- I am trying to parse "Saut� Pans" here "�" is a special character and Ktor throws an exception saying :- `io.ktor.utils.io.charsets.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1`. Now I have tried passing different headers for example passing different `ContentType` to `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-2` but didn't help.

Whereas parsing the same api response with `Gson()` works for me.

Any solution or workaround so that for now so that I can parse such kind of special characters in my response ?

Comment: Could you please describe an example response from a server?

Comment: It is an array of some products which contains id and name and the name field has some special charcters in it

Comment: I mean could you please share an example HTTP response with headers and body?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out

```
install(ContentEncoding){
    gzip()
}
```

Comment: not sure what is gzip() ? It cannot import or do anything